# Using react-select Async with loadOptions and redux-form

Tags: forms, reactjs, select, redux, react-select

I'm using `react-select` library to display a select box. I'm using `Select.Async` because I need to pull my options from an API. I use `Select` with `loadOptions` and it works during the intial page render. However, I'm also using `redux-form` which can change the value of a `Field` dynamically (using `change`). However, when I change the value of the Field like this, the value of the input does change (and I can verify this), but react-select's `loadOptions` is never called again (even though I thought it was supposed to be listening to a change of value). My question is, is there a way to dynamicaly call loadOptions every time the input value changes?

Thanks,

Edit: Answered on github [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1879#issuecomment-319278331)

Answer (score -1):

It might be a better solution than this, but a quick one is to set a `ref` to your `Select.Async` component, and when a change action is triggered (like the change of an input - your case, or one button click event - like in the code below) you can update its options. I'm using a similar example with the example of [their](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select#async-options) docs.

```
class YourClass extends React.Component {

  getOptions = (input, callback) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      callback(null, {
        options: [
          {value: 'one', label: 'One'},
          {value: 'two', label: 'Two'}
        ]
       });
     }, 500);
   };   

  updateOptions = () => {
    this.selectAsync.state.options.push(
      {value: 'three', label: 'Three'}
    )
  }

  render() {
    let props = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Select.Async
          ref={selectAsync => this.selectAsync = selectAsync}
          loadOptions={this.getOptions}
        />
        <button onClick={this.updateOptions}>
          Load more items
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
this.state = {
            store: '',
            
        };
        
         this.handleStoreSelect = this.handleStoreSelect.bind(this);
         
         
          handleStoreSelect = (item) => {
        this.setState({
            store: item.value
        }
    };
    
    <Select.Async
                              
                              name="storeID"
                              value={this.state.store}
                              loadOptions={getStores}
                              onChange={this.handleStoreSelect}
                            />
```

```js
const getStores = () => {
    return fetch(
          "api to be hit",
          {
              method: 'get',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
          }
        )
          .then(response => {
              if(response.status >= 400){
                  throw new Error("error");
              }
              return response.json()
          })
          .then(stores => {
              let ret = [];


              for(let store of stores) {
                  ret.push({value: store._id, label: store.name})
              }


              return {options: ret};
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log('could not fetch data');
              console.log(err);
              return {options: []}
          })

};
```

Using this we can fetch the data and pass this object in the loadoptions.
copy this code outside the class. and also i'm posting the code to be implemented for loadoptions

Comment: It doesn't answer the question (you don't use redux-form)